# How to respond to an editor who suddenly stops answering your emails

Tags: publications, editors, books

I've been corresponding with an editor at a university publishing company, but he suddenly stopped responding to my emails. Most recently, I sent him my book chapters and a summary of my book, but he has not gotten back to me, even though it has been a month since I sent him the email (in the meantime, I sent him another email, and also called him to confirm). 
Should I take this as a sign that the editor is no longer interested in my work? Or should I try reaching him one more time?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the explanation lies elsewhere. If he loses interest he would most likely tell you to "buzz off" using some polite language.

More likely is that something has come up in his real or professional life. Also possible is that you were a bit too chatty, requesting more feedback than there was time for. It is also possible that things have been going along well on the current state of your work but just isn't ripe enough for action at this time.

But you can certainly ask whether there is anything you need to do now and what time frame  can you expect for the next required action.

Answer (score -1):

This is sadly a really common problem in the world of humanities publishing. Acquisition editors are often overworked, trying to balance the responsibilities of developing new projects, editing current ones, and moving projects through peer review. Given the importance that book projects have for careers, however, this isn't great.

You've been doing the right things – "in the meantime, I sent him another email, and also called him to confirm." I had a graduate student in a similar position, and here is what I would recommend:

- Send another short and firm e-mail, asking to acknowledge receipt and noting that you understand the busy workload. I would try to keep this a two-sentence email.
- If you don't hear within two weeks from that, if you need this for tenure/promotion/hiring, I would begin to **find another university press**. If they're lagging at this stage, they're going to lag at other stages: (a) finding peer reviewers (if applicable); (b) working with their Board of Directors; (c) moving this project to production.

Good luck. It isn't a comment on your work, likely, but rather a representation of their disorganized working habits.